# Download speed slower when connecting to a distant server

Tags: windows, networking, download

Earlier this year I noticed that the download speed from my computer was way slower than it was and should be: I have 500Mbps with my ISP provider and last year had download speeds at up to 65MB/s on Steam, which is all good. But a few months ago I noticed a drop in my download speed and could never pass 10MB/s. After testing, I noticed that the further away the server, the slower the download speed was... But not by a few. Somewhere around 50% loss in speed per 1000km. So I tested in my wife's computer and everything was fine, so no issue with the internet provider or the router (used the same cable to test it).

I decided to not pursue how to fix this and just reinstalled windows. It worked. But today I ran into the same problem again... I searched around and could not solve the problem.

Before reinstalling windows I was running on Windows 10 and now I'm on Windows 11 (don't think this is relevant).

What I tried:

- Restarting PC and Router;
- Windows network troubleshoot (why not);
- Manually reset the TCP/IP stack, release and renew the IP address and flush and reset the DNS client with this commands:

  - netsh winsock reset
  - netsh int ip reset
  - ipconfig /release
  - ipconfig /renew
  - ipconfig /flushdns
- Uninstalled all network adaptors drivers and reinstalled only the realtek one:

  - I also uninstalled hamachi, forticlient and tunnelbear
- Used the network reset option in windows' advanced network settings.

After each of those steps I rebooted the computer with no relevant changes to the internet speed. Anyone ever had this problem or has an idea how to fix it?

EDIT:
I'm measuring the download speed with speedtest.net and tried different servers. All servers that are in the same city I'm in (pings under 5ms) that I tried are measuring over 500Mbps, I tried a few in different cities (pings up to 20ms) and never got over 200Mbps and tried a few more distant servers (pings up to 70ms) and never got over 80Mbps.
I also tried with fiber.google.com/speedtest/ and got similar results.

UPDATE:
So... I reseted the windows and reinstalled it and it fixed the problem. I'll try to discover what is triggering this problem and I'll update the question if I ever discover what is causing it. Thanks to everyone that read it and tried to solve it.

Comment: What's the rtt / latency / ping time to the servers in question? (It affects TCP's maximum achievable speed.) Does the problem affect all distant servers equally, or does it maybe correlate e.g. to a specific ISP showing up in traceroute?

Comment: How do you measure the download speed? Some protocols are more sensitive to latency and packet loss than others.

Comment: I'm measuring the download speed with speedtest.net and tried different servers. All servers that are in the same city I'm in (pings under 5ms) that I tried are measuring over 500Mbps, I tried a few in different cities (pings up to 20ms) and never got over 200Mbps and tried a few more distant servers (pings up to 70ms) and never got over 80Mbps.

Comment: I also tried with fiber.google.com/speedtest/ and got similar results.

Comment: @BlindSpots done